# Curious Memory Footprint for Java.exe when running Selenium-Grid

Tags: java, garbage-collection, selenium-webdriver

Java noob here.

I am seeing 'strange' memory behaviour when running a Selenium Grid with the following java.exe process.

> java.exe -jar selenium-grid.jar -role hub -port 84 -timeout 100

The "Private Bytes" metric in Task Manager slowly rises at about 100 MB / minute until it gets to concerning sizes (>20 GB!).

I haven't determined if it's actually causing problems. I just suspect healthy processes don't get that big. I attach YourKit profiler and see a very very healthy heap hovering at < 350 MB [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Avz.png).

[image: YourKit profile of java.exe running Selenium Grid]

YourKit allows me to Force a GC operation inside of the JVM, so I go for it and the "Private Bytes' drops from 20 GB to ~500 MB. So there is no leak or anything.

I do a little reading about GC settings and start playing with -Xmx and -Xincgc and get some slightly different behaviour but I always end up with this whacking-huge process which goes through huge GC operations. Some people on my team think this is degrading reliability but I don't have any causal data at this time.

So I'm posting out of curiosity. 
Does anybody run Selenium Grid with customized GC settings?
GC experts - any thoughts here - is anything about this unhealthy?

- Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
- 32 GB RAM w/ Xeon 2x L5640 2.27GHz
- JRE SE 7 U9
- Selenium WebDriver 2.31.0.0

Comment: `-port 84` <-- don't tell me you are running the program as a priviledged user?

Comment: yes. i am due to the nature of the hosting environment i am in. would that impact this?

Comment: No, the JVM does nothing particular in that case. I was just mentioning the fact, that's all...

Comment: Is this Windows or Linux? What version of the 64-bit JVM is this? JDK or JRE?  If you profile the classes (using JVisualVM or YourKit), which classes are eating up all the memory?

Comment: @djangofan - Windows Server 2012 Datacenter. JRE SE 7 U9. The profiler shows that very little memory is being used (so I can't trace it back to classes). However, the Windows OS shows that a lot of memory is being used (private bytes). I am hoping to understand the gap and decide if it is unhealthy ...

Comment: @Kenn - the memory size in your screenshots is still very small.  350MB is not unusual for Nodes since each Firefox instance could consume 100MB+ . can you clarify what you think is too large on your Hub and how many sessions are you running?